# How to Open a div when navigation between two different pages?

Tags: jquery

I have two pages namely

```
Customer.html
index.html
```

I am redirecting from one page to another page as shown

**Customer.html**

```
  window.location = "customer/index.html?qruuid="+uuid;
```

**index.html**

I am retrieving qruuid value and redirecting back to Customer.html

```
else if(qruuid!='')
 {
window.location = "../Customer.html?UUID="+qruuid;

 }
```

My question here is that when i am redirecting back (from index.html to Customer.html) page

is it possible to show the Customer.html with a particular div open ??

That is i have a class  named "`restaurantmenu`" under Customer.html and i want to show that in opened state  when i redirect back

```
$("#restaurantmenu").show();
```

Comment: You could look for the query string (or referrer) and if it's the right one, trigger `$("#restaurantmenu").show();` on page load.

Comment: could you please let me know what is query string ??

Comment: The part of the URL after the `?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more parameter when you redirect from index.HTML to customer.HTML. something like

```
window.location = "../Customer.html?UUID="+qruuid+";isDivOpen=true;";
```

retrieve the parameter isDivOpen and if it true. then

```
$("#restaurantmenu").show();
```

Comment: I am using Jquery , so you mean under jquery's ready function i should do this ??

Answer (score 1):

If the return URL is `"../Customer.html?UUID="+qruuid`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  s = location.search;
  if(s.indexOf('qruuid') != -1) {
   $("#restaurantmenu").show();
  }
});
```